# SFDX & Github Action - Warning: force:auth:sfdxurl:store is not a sfdx command

Tags: github-actions, salesforce-cli

I have the following yaml file. It were working just fine until yesterday. Unfortunately starting from today received the below warning and followed by the following error.

Hope someone will be able to point me to solution to fixed this issue. Below is the yaml code

```
name: CI_dev

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ dev ]

jobs:
  test_pipeline:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
    # Install Salesforce CLI
    - name: Install Salesforce CLI
      run: |
          wget https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sfdx-linux-amd64.tar.xz
          mkdir sfdx-cli
          tar xJf sfdx-linux-amd64.tar.xz -C sfdx-cli --strip-components 1
          ./sfdx-cli/install
          
    #Checkout master
    - name: 'checkout master'
      uses: actions/checkout@master

    #read secret, authenticate and deploy
    - name: 'Populate auth file with SFDX_URL secret'
      shell: bash
      run: 'echo ${{ secrets.secret}} > ./secret.txt'

    - name: 'Authenticate'
      run: 'sfdx force:auth:sfdxurl:store --sfdxurlfile=./secret.txt -a secretAlias' 
      
    - name: 'Deploy'
      run: "sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath ./force-app/main/default -l RunLocalTests -u secretAlias"
```

Below is the warning that appear on the authenticate step

```
Warning: force:auth:sfdxurl:store is not a sfdx command.
Did you mean auth:sfdxurl:store? [y/n]:
```

And below is the error that appear on the Deploy step

```
ERROR running force:source:deploy:  No org configuration found for name secretAlias
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Did you try run it locally?

Comment: locally using windows its working. but i think you are given valid point. i can try using vm linux in local

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sfdx (at least linux distributions) have recently updated from 7.82.1 to 7.83.1  (January 2021)

since 7.83.1 it follows different syntax format.
You need to remove `force:` from your 'Authenticate' command line as it is advised in error message.

You can look your current version with:

```
sfdx --version
```

Comment: why isn't this documented? why only sfdx linux distributions have been affected?

Comment: Windows distributions could be affected too, but I can't tell right now which version is now on Windows and how it behaves.

Answer (score 0):

Busy Box was right. just need to remove force from force:auth and its alread working again. below is the updated yaml file as reference.

```
name: CI_dev

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ dev ]

jobs:
  test_pipeline:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
    # Install Salesforce CLI
    - name: Install Salesforce CLI
      run: |
          wget https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sfdx-linux-amd64.tar.xz
          mkdir sfdx-cli
          tar xJf sfdx-linux-amd64.tar.xz -C sfdx-cli --strip-components 1
          ./sfdx-cli/install
          
    #Checkout master
    - name: 'checkout master'
      uses: actions/checkout@master

    #read secret, authenticate and deploy
    - name: 'Populate auth file with SFDX_URL secret'
      shell: bash
      run: 'echo ${{ secrets.secret}} > ./secret.txt'

    - name: 'Authenticate'
      run: 'sfdx auth:sfdxurl:store --sfdxurlfile=./secret.txt -a secretAlias' 
      
    - name: 'Deploy'
      run: "sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath ./force-app/main/default -l RunLocalTests -u secretAlias"
```